# making a custom css rule

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to make a custom rule in Css as @media 
I have a parent class and need to make  changes depended on this class as

```
    <div class="parentGreen"> 
          <ul class="ul1">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="ul2">
           <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

so when i change the parentGreen the items inside their css changes too

```
@parentGreen{
    ul{
direction: ltr
}
}

@parentYellow{
  ul{
direction: rtl;
margin:10px;
}
}
```

Comment: Use css classes inside your media selector? :/ `.parentGreen ul {...}` and `parentYellow ul {...}`

Comment: @DominicTobias i need to  group them more than that

Answer (score 3):

Compiled version on this link is what you want.

Do you hear about **less**? Try searching about it. Less is better choice for creating nested css. You can write like this:

```
.parent {
    .child1 {
      color: blue;
    }
    .child2 {
      color: blue;
    }
}
```

[Look this link.](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.parent%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26.child1%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26.child2%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

Comment: This is incorrect, the `&` are not needed - as it stands, `.parent { &.child1 { .. } }` compiles to `.parent.child1 { .. }` which is not right ;)

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks for warning.

Comment: however i dont want to use a pre-processor css

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
.parentGreen ul {
    direction: ltr
}

.parentYellow ul {
    direction: rtl;
    margin:10px;
}
```